# modal dialog in gwt with clicklistener

Tags: gwt, modal-dialog

I've a huge panel with drop-down lists and checkboxes. To manage them I have to implement the ClickListener interface so that on expanding the drop-down list or clicking on the checkbox some actions are executed.

Then I have to show the dialog box with just one 'OK' button and this dialog should be modal. I create it using via the following constructor

```
    final DialogBox msg = new DialogBox(false, true);
```

so it should be modal and it is except for drop-down lists and checkboxes because clicking on them calls to the onClick(Widget sender) method which knows nothing about the modality of the dialog box so it could expand the drop-down list or tick the checkbox.

I see that this could be resolved by just one if in that onClick() method where it should check if there is no modal window or there is one. But is there another option to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [setGlassEnabled(boolean)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html#setGlassEnabled(boolean))?